# How to center the pagenumber related to the page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

My pagemark in the heading is centered related to the textbody, but since my left margin is wider than my right, the pagenumber is not centered related to the page.

Little miniature example:

```
\documentclass[ 
    12pt, % Schriftgröße 
    %DIV10,  % Teilung der Seite in 10 Teile (Layout bessere Lesbarkeit) 
    ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc. 
    a4paper, % Papierformat 
    oneside, % einseitiges Dokument (Standard) 
    titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet 
    parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile) 
    headings=normal, % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern 
    listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen 
    bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen 
    %index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen 
    captions=tableheading, % Beschriftung von Tabellen unterhalb ausgeben 
    final % Status des Dokuments (final/draft) 
]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[ 
    %automark, % Kapitelangaben in Kopfzeile automatisch erstellen 
    %headsepline, % Trennlinie unter Kopfzeile 
    ilines % Trennlinie linksbündig ausrichten 
]{scrpage2} 

\begin{document} 


% Kopf- und Fußzeilen ---------------------------------------------------------- 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
% Kopf- und Fußzeile auch auf Kapitelanfangsseiten 
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 
% Schriftform der Kopfzeile 
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont} 

% Kopfzeile 
\ihead{} 
\chead{\pagemark}    %TODO das muss ich noch zentrieren 
\ohead{} 
%\setlength{\headheight}{21mm} % Höhe der Kopfzeile 
% Kopfzeile über den Text hinaus verbreitern 
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar} 
\setheadsepline[text]{0pt} % Trennlinie unter Kopfzeile entfernen 

% arabische Seitenzahlen im Hauptteil ------------------------------------------ 
\clearpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
Das hier soll dann ein Text sein. 
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you _really_ want to do that? At the moment I can't see why you'd want to.

Comment: Because that's what my Student's-Book says. I have to have a certain format for my Bachelorsthesis. And that's how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how to fix it:

```
\setheadwidth[-1.35in]{page}
```

"page" sets the headwidth from the standard (text) to page. Somehow that didn't quite worked, so I added the optional parameter. 
THX for your help, otherwise I wouldn't have found out!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
\chead{\kern-1in\pagemark}
```

Comment: I tried it again at home with my original tex file and it did not work. But somehow it worked fine with my miniature example when I used the geometry-package.

Comment: then you do something special. It is not possible to say more without a minimal example

Comment: How can I find out more about my problem, do you have any idea? I already looked through the file if I changed something, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: `... \begin{document} foo \end{document}` and then uncomment the preamble from the bottom to the top until the problem went away.

Comment: that's a fantastic idea, thank you very much, I will try that on Friday (tomorrow CeBit) and update the status here.